# Last stone weight 2 in javascript, 1d array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming

[last stone weight 2 solution in cpp](https://leetcode.com/problems/last-stone-weight-ii/discuss/635621/Dp-solution-with-explaination-(cpp))

This is able to pass all test cases.

```
class Solution {
   public:
   int lastStoneWeightII(vector<int>& stones) {
      int n = stones.size();
      int total = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         total += stones[i];
      }
      int req = total / 2;
      vector <bool> dp(req + 1, false);
      dp[0] = true;
      int reach = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         for(int j = req; j - stones[i] >= 0; j--){
            dp[j] = dp[j] || dp[j - stones[i]];
            if(dp[j]) reach = max(reach, j);
         }
      }
      return total - (2 * reach);
   }
};
```

I tried to replicate it in javascript and not able to pass
a simple test cases like `[2,7,4,1,8,1]`

Here is my attempt

```
var lastStoneWeightII = function(st) {
    // stone #
    const n = st.length;
    // sum up
    const sum = st.reduce((acc, curr) => {return acc+curr});
    // e.g. half
    const ha = Math.floor(sum / 2);
    
    // half+1
    const dp = Array(ha+1).fill(false);
    // 1st ele = true
    dp[0] = true;
   
    // store tmp_max
    let max = 0;
    // loop element
    for(let i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // single element
        const w = n[i];
        // backward, half
        for(let j=ha; j-w>=0; j--) {
            // update condi
            dp[j] = dp[j] || dp[j-w]; 
                
            // never comes in
            if(dp[j]) {
                //test
                console.log('++++ max', max, 'j', j)
                max = Math.max(max, j);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return (sum - max) - max;
}
```

Comment: have you checked what you have written? pass row by row and you will see the difference (surprised that `const w = n[i];` compiles since `n` is the length of the array...)

Comment: In the link: `So for example, if the input is like [2,7,4,1,8,1], then the output will be 1. This is because if we smash (2,4), then the new array will be [2,7,1,8,1], them smash (7,8), the new array will be [2,1,1,1], then smash (2,1), the array will be [1,1,1], after that smash (1,1), so only 1 will be there.` is inconclusive(no definition for order of smashing): if we go "in order", [2,7,4,1,8,1], (2,7)->(5)->[5,4,1,8,1], (5,4)->(1)->[1,1,8,1], (1,1)->()->[8,1], (8,1)->(7)->[7]->only 7 will be there...